# Naming convention for classes in test code

Tags: java, junit

Assume I have classes `ClassX` in production code (`src/main/java`) and `ClassXTest` in test code (`src/test/java`). In some test methods I want to tamper what one of the methods of `ClassX` returns, so I override `ClassX` and its method. I do not want to use any mocking frameworks or this class to be anonymous. Is there any naming how such classes should be named?

Comment: This doesn't make sense; if you're testing `ClassX`, why would you want to override it during your test?

Comment: Either to fake the value  it returns (for example to return constant instead of accessing WS or DB) or to sense something (for example to store the value of the parameter so that it could be checked later).

Comment: To test an abstract class you also have to extend it.

Comment: In the former case, you should be ideally opting for dependency injection. If you're overriding, you're not actually testing your code.

Comment: Good point. But if I am testing one aspect, I don't care that the other aspect is not tested in this test, but is tested in other tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes are called "test-specific subclasses" and there doesn't seem to by any naming convention. http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html gives some examples of overriding classes that are under tests.

Comment: Such classes are also called "Testing subclasses" and I've seen advice to prepend `Testing` prefix to their name. For example, production class `Server`, test case class `ServerTest` and testing subclass `TestingServer`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would call these classes: `ClassXTestImpl`

It's not the greatest naming convention in the world, but it makes it obvious that it is test code and is not expected to be used by the production code. You could also make it a private inner class of the test class in which it is being used, then it wouldn't even be accessible by you production code.

Generally, I don't like calling things `Impl`, but in this case, the `ClassX` part will define what the class actually does and the `TestImpl` bit is just to mark it as a test implementation.

---

An aside about partial mocking:

I know you said that you didn't want to use mocking frameworks, but if you're replacing `method1` in order to make `method2` easier to test and both methods reside in the same class, then what you're doing is a form of partial mocking, whether you do it with a framework or not. It's difficult to find documentation for Partial Mocking that isn't linked to a particular framework, so I'll provide [EasyMock's documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-partial) but point out that most mocking frameworks support this kind of mocking.